# Fine-Grained Policy IAM Condition Using Cognito User Pool Sub Property

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I want to access the same **sub** property in my role policy as the sub property that is given to me in the Post Confirmation callback from Cognito.  I have tried:

cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub
and 
cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{poolId}:sub

so my policy includes:

```
        "Condition": {
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                    <<line here>>
                ]
            }
        }
```

but neither seem to work.  Both lead to the same access denied errors.  My policy works without the condition statement

Is there a way to reference the sub that is created by the cognito user pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only IAM variable Cognito has is for the federated identity, where sub maps to identity id. To map a policy to a user, you'll have to get link your user pools user to an identity in your identity pool, and then using that to do so.

Comment: Thank you for the response Jeff, is there any guarantee that a pool user will always have the same sub in the federated identity id?  For instance, if my user logs out and back in, will they have the same sub on future logins?

Comment: Yes, unless you merge another identity with the one associated with the user pool user. If you don't it'll be the same

Comment: Did you manage to get the Cognito User Pool Sub in an IAM Policy? I'm having the same problem with a DynamoDB Policy. And I don't understand what @JeffBailey meant with linking a user pool user to an identity.